# How to create generic swift function that can work for 2 different classes?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

In my two classes, I have the following code

```
// Two classes who's code I am trying to reduce using protocols
class class1 {
    var view: viewSubclass1!
    func printName() {
        print("This is the view: \(view)")
    }
}

class class2 {
    var view: viewSubclass2!
    func printName() {
        print("This is the view: \(view)")
    }
}

// The protocol and protocol extension I am trying to create
protocol myProtocol {
    var view: UIView {get set}
    func printName()
}

extension myProtocol {
    func printName() {
        print("This is the view: \(view)")
    }
}

// The subviews of UIView
class viewSubclass1: UIView {}
class viewSubclass2: UIView {}
```

As you can see, `class1` and `class2` are different classes, but have the same variable name: `view` and the same function names. The difference is that the `view` variable are of different types.

**Question: Using protocols and protocol-extensions, how can I reduce the code between the two classes?** I would not want to do repeat code because they are so similar. I have been trying different variations of the code, but I keep getting stuck. I do not understand it well.  **How can i get both classes to use the same code using a protocol, and a protocol extension?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Updated)**

With declaring the protocol and protocol extension:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype BaseView: UIView
    var view: BaseView! {get set}
    func printName()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func printName() {
        print("This is the view: \(view)")
    }
}
```

And given two subclasses of UIView:

```
class ViewSubclass1: UIView {}
class ViewSubclass2: UIView {}
```

(Capitalized some type names for readability.)

And declaring two classes like this:

```
class Class1: MyProtocol {
    var view: ViewSubclass1!
}

class Class2: MyProtocol {
    var view: ViewSubclass2!
}
```

You'll find you can use your `printName()` for both `Class1` and `Class2`.

One thing important here:

If you declare your `view` in the protocol as `var view: UIView {get set}`, `var view: ViewSubclass1!` cannot fulfill the requirement for the protocol.
(One thing is the difference of optionality, another is that you cannot assign any instances of `UIView` or `UIView`'s subclasses to `view: ViewSubclass1`.)

But many things depend on what you really want to do in your common code.

Comment: I have edited my question. The first one was a mess. I have tried to make it more simple.

Comment: @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift, ok, I'll update my answer later.